# Select the records that matches the month value in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have selected the records which matches the given month name and using simple cursor adapter i have to display it in listview. I'm getting no error but the list displays nothing.

Here is my code

```
public Cursor readData(String month){
    String SELECT_MON = "select * from " + Diary_DBHandler.TABLE_PERSONAL + " where strftime('%m'," +Diary_DBHandler.PERSONAL_DATE + ") = '" + month +"';";
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(SELECT_MON, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

Cursor c = dbcon.readData(month);

    String[] from = new String[]{Diary_DBHandler.PERSONAL_ID,Diary_DBHandler.PERSONAL_TITLE,Diary_DBHandler.PERSONAL_DESC,Diary_DBHandler.PERSONAL_AMT_SPENT,
            Diary_DBHandler.PERSONAL_PAYMETHOD, Diary_DBHandler.PERSONAL_DATE };
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.persID_tv,R.id.persTitle_tv,R.id.persDesc_tv,R.id.persAmt_tv,
            R.id.persPaymethod_tv, R.id.persDate_tv};

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Diary_ListOfPersonalExpenses.this,R.layout.diary_personal_exp_entries,c,from,to);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: What is the value of `month`?

Comment: April, May like name is the month value

Answer (score 0):

The [strftime documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) says:

> `%m`   month: 01-12

You have to convert `month`'s value into the same format for the comparison to work.

Comment: Now i converted the month value to number like for april 04. But its not working

Comment: Edited my code. Could you please check whats the mistake?

Comment: Do not change the question to something different; this would invalidate any previous answers. If you have a new question, ask a new question.